# How do you solve Import "django_filters.views" could not be resolvedPylance error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, module, django-filters

I suddenly received this error when I opened vscode:

```
Import "django_filters.views" could not be resolvedPylance(reportMissingImports)
```

I was programming a django project about a month ago using vscode, but I didn't work on the project for about a month since I had other things to do. However, when I opened my vscode to start working on the project again, I received the above error. New edits in the code seem to be a grey color now as well. I think vscode got automatically updated while I was away, but I have no idea why this issue is occurring. I hope you guys could help me find the problem. If there is any information you need, please comment below. Thanks.

I don't know if this would help, but I found the following article that states that "Pylance is now the default language server for Python in Visual Studio Code, providing IntelliSense functionality as of the May 2021 release of the Python Extension for VS Code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is related to Pylance Language Server.

You need to add this in your settings.json file(if django_filters folder just under the folder you opened in the VSCode):

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/django_filters"]
```

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings) for more details.

**Update**:

If you want to roll back, you can add or update this configuration in the settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "JediLSP",
```

And

**${workspaceFolder}** means the path of the folder opened in VS Code.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. Can you please help me with the following two questions that I can't seem to find an appropriate answer for? First of all, is it okay to just disable or delete the pylance extension newly added to the vscode? (This seemed to remove the error, and I am currently working on my project with the pylance disabled) Secondly, would you mind showing the windows version for the code above(I think the $ is for mac... I don't know honestly)? Thanks a lot, and I hope you could help me with these questions.

Comment: You can switch to another language server with "python.languageServer" configuration in the settings.json file. Such as: "python.languageServer": "JediLSP". And ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code. You can refer to here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference.

Comment: Sure thing. But just one last clarification please. Can I just disable pylance extension, and  everything would work back as normal? Or is there a problem with disabling pylance? Thanks again. Sorry for constantly asking you.

Comment: Thanks for helping! But, I still don't know if it is okay to disable my pylance extension. I don't know if I should just enable it after I copy and pasted the above JediLSP code to my setting.json.

Comment: No, Pylance is one choice of "python.languageServer", you can switch to Pylance with: "python.languageServer": "Pylance".